# git pull fatal error server repo

Tags: git, git-pull

My goal is to set up a repo on my lab server, which I can clone on my laptop via ssh. I still want a working copy on the server.  Here is what I did:

server:

> > mkdir myProject
> >
> > git --init
> >
> > (add some files and commit them so it' isn't empty)
> >
> > git clone --bare ~/myProject/.git/ ~/git/myrepo.git

laptop:

> > git clone erin@labserver.edu:/home/erin/myrepo.git
> >
> > git add file1
> >
> > git commit
> >
> > git push

server:

> > git pull

then I get this error:

> > fatal: Where do you want to fetch from today?

Do you have an idea of what could be wrong?  I tried following the branching/ staging/rebasing directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756600/when-youre-the-origin-repo-in-git-how-do-you-do-a-local-pull), but it didn't fix the problem.  Also

> > git pull origin master

didn't fix it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've followed the steps you've listed, and I can't reproduce the error that you're getting (`fatal: Where do you want to fetch from today?`). However, if you've followed the steps that you've written out in the question, `server` doesn't have any remote repositories - `git pull` won't work, because `server` doesn't have any remotes to pull from. I think that is the cause of the error you're getting.

At the moment, you've got three repositories: on **server**: `myProject`, `myRepo`, and on **laptop** `myRepo` (clone from `server`). If my understanding of the question is correct, you want to use `myProject` (on `server`) and `myRepo` (on `Laptop`) to work from. I assume you've got `myRepo` (on `server`) as a staging ground that you can `git push` and `git pull` from; you've done that correctly, because you've set it up as a `--bare` repository, which is a smart move.

If you follow `triad`'s instructions in his answer, you'll end up with two repositories: `server`, which is a `--bare` repository, and `laptop`. If you're comfortable re-setting up your repositories, I would follow `triad`s instructions, something like this:

1. Make a `--bare` repository somewhere. This is going to be the staging ground. Call it something useful, like `bareRepository` or something.
2. You have a repository with some work in it. In that repository (on `server` or `laptop`), add `bareRepository` to your list of remotes: `git remote add <name> <url>`.
3. `git push` your work from the repository in (2) to `bareRepository`. That'll ensure that `bareRepository` is up-to-date and whatnot.
4. Because you can't work out of `bareRepository`, clone it again on which ever computer does not have a working repository (`server` or `laptop`). Because you're cloning `bareRepository`, git will treat `bareRepository` as the `origin`; you can `git push origin` and `git pull origin` to your hearts content, without messing up a repository with a work tree.
5. Once you've set up the two working repositories (one on `laptop`, one on `server`) and a `--bare` repository (on either `laptop` or `server`), you should be able to sync your work happily:

   - do some work
   - `git commit` the work
   - `git push origin` - get the work to the bare repo
   - On the other computer: `git pull origin` to update your branch.